# Django web app that detects a smart-phone user's position

Tags: javascript, python, django, html

I want to build a web app using Django-Python that will be mainly used from smart-phones. I want the app to be able to detect the user's position and showcase it into a google maps front end. Basically, I want the app to be something like google maps GPS and then I will make some calculations with the coordinates and print out to the user some alternatives. I want the user's coordinates to be updated when he walks for example.

Do you have any suggestions about what modules, libraries or packages can I use to get this done? I found some packages like djangocms-gmaps but I am not sure if this is the right way to go.

Comment: Make a Django app, then get your user's GPS location via their browser. To do this, you also need some JavaScript/HTML5 knowledge. A good place to start reading about this is this page from Google - https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location/ and this page from Mozilla - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation. And finally read Google Maps API docs to plot their position in a map.

Comment: @xyres Will the user be able to give me the position just by simply turning on location? Thank you for the answer

Comment: Uh, not so *simply*. You see, you'll write the JavaScript code to access their location. When the user turns on location for your web app, your browser will give your JavaScript code the location co-ordinates. Then, you can write some more JS code to send these co-ordinates to your Django backend using AJAX. Basically, it means that you can send data to your server without reloading the page ([Read about AJAX here](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/)). So, finally now that you've sent the user's location to your Django server, you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: @AlexandrosKazantzidis Geolocation is a privacy matter. Users need to give the site approval to give out geolocation. I added a answer with code example.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a function provided by Django. More javascript anf HTML5

Here is a example snippet that you ofcourse can use with a Django project.

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>
```